# Static field or property cannot be assigned in an object initializer. C#

Tags: c#, static, visual-studio-2013

I have been trying to get this class to work. When I remove static from all of the methods the class works but I am unable to call the display() from a different class. In order to call the display() I have to make it static along with everything else in the class. Now I am getting an error "Static field or property 'trackName' cannot be assigned in an object initializer' for this line of code:
`tracklist.Add(new Tracklist() {trackName=track, minutes=Minutes, seconds=Seconds});`
I am also getting the error with 'minutes' and 'seconds'.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.IEnumerable;

namespace Music
{
class Tracklist
{
    public static string trackName { get; set; }
    public static int minutes { get; set; }
    public static int seconds { get; set; }
    //public string strng { get; set; }
    public static List<Tracklist> tracklist = new List<Tracklist>();
    //public static List<string> TrackListString = new List<string>();
    //public static string[] popper;

    public Tracklist()
    {
        //public List<Tracklist> tracklist = new List<Tracklist>();
        display();
    }
    public static void add(string track, int Minutes, int Seconds)
    {
        //string strng = Track.Track(track,Minutes,Seconds);
        tracklist.Add(new Tracklist() {trackName=track, minutes=Minutes, seconds=Seconds});
        //tracklist.Add(trackName=track, minutes=Minutes, seconds=Seconds);
        //new Tracklist() { strng };
    }
    public static int count()
    {
        return tracklist.Count;
    }
    public static string ToString()
    {
        int i=0;
        string[] holder=new string[count()];
        string c = "";
        foreach(object strng in tracklist)
        {
            string a = Track.Track(trackName, minutes, seconds);
            string b = (Convert.ToString(i+1) + ") " + a + Environment.NewLine);
            c = c + b;
            //TrackListString.Add(new string() { strng = b });
            holder[i] = b;
            i++;
            //return b;
        }
        return c; 
    }
    public static string getTrackAt(int i)
    {
        //string TrackAtI= tracklist.[i].trackName; // not sure what is heppening here
        string test = tracklist.ElementAt(i).trackName;
        return test;
    }
    public static void display()
    {
        string holder = ToString();
        Console.Write(holder);
    }       
}}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Why do you use static properties and methods?! I think using of static key word isn't necessary for your project!!

Comment: I made all of my properties non-static and got the code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display()` should not be static, because when you display a track list, you intend to display an instance of a track list. Making it static would mean that you display the notion of track lists in general, not a specific track list.

This is also the reason why you're getting this error. You're creating an instance of track list by calling `new Tracklist()`, but `trackName` is not a property of a track list. It is static, making it a property of the notion of track lists in general. There's no trackName per track list, there's only one track name in the world!

If `trackName` is kept static, it means that `tracklist1.trackName` is llegal. There's only `Tracklist.trackName`, so there's only one track name in the world.

Comment: In my other class I call the display in the Tracklist class. By making the display not static I get an error in the other class that reads "An object reference for the non-static field, method, or property 'Music.Tracklist.display()'.

Comment: @Maclover25 That's probably because you're calling display() on the class: `Tracklist.display()`, while you **should** call it on an instance: `var tl = new Tracklist(); tl.display();`

Answer (score 0):

You have this sub-expression:

```
new Tracklist() {trackName=track, minutes=Minutes, seconds=Seconds}
```

but the properties `trackName`, `minutes`, `seconds` are **`static`** properties. So they don't belong to the new `Tracklist` *instance* you have created. The error message is clear:

> Static field or property cannot be assigned in an object initializer.

An "object initializer" is an expression like (example):

```
new NameOfType() { Property1 = expr1, Property2 = expr2, }
```

It makes a new instance (a new object) of the type, and sets each of the properties on that type. Therefore the properties must certainly be instance properties, a.k.a. non-static properties.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the other answer that `display()` should not be static. But if that's the case then the rest of your class should not be static either. I'm assuming that you're trying to implement a singleton here.  Firstly, as also mentioned above, trackName, minutes and seconds can't be static. But you can add a static constructor to initialize your single instance:

```
static class TrackList
{
    static TrackList()
    {
        tracklist = new List<TrackList>();
    }
}
```

The non-static constructor is the source of the error.

Comment: Singletons are a bad practice except for very extraordinary circumstances, especially the kind that are instantiated in the static constuctor (*WTF?*) and this is a piece of spectacularly bad advice from the point of view of object-oriented design.